# Programmatically edit EdgeCollider2D vertices

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way to programmatically edit the vertices of EdgeCollider2D in Unity2D? Like programmatically edit each vertex and it's location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can edit them using [EdgeCollider2D.points](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EdgeCollider2D-points.html) array.